# Puppet configuration file on Windows

Tags: windows, puppet

I'm running puppet on windows as an admin (testing on windows 7, even though it is not officially supported). When I install puppet following the windows installation instructions, no puppet.conf file is generated in C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/etc. I can run puppet agent --genconfig to create one, but regardless of what values I put in there, it doesn't seem to respect them.

Is this just a puppet/windows issue? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why not startup [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), then run the agent.  Filter on puppet, and see what files it tries to open.

Comment: I'll give that a try and see what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What does `puppet agent --configprint config` show?

That command will print the configuration value for `config`, which is the path to the configuration file itself.

Are you perhaps running `puppet agent` without administrator privileges and thus Puppet is looking in your home directory for `puppet.conf` ?

Comment: It showed the correct values and I have admin privileges. It is on windows though, so it could just be a puppet/windows issue. I'll have to revisit this.